# Nodejs - 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: mysql, node.js

- Gone thru difference similar posts on stack but could not resolve problem
- My Nodejs with MySql app is working fine locally but when I host in on A2Hosting.com, it gives me 503 Service ..... error
- Exact Error is as follow:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

- My Other simple Nodejs app is working fine on A2Hosting
- Index.html is simple hello mesaage

server.js

```
  var express = require('express');
            var path = require('path');
            var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
            var mysql = require('mysql');

            var index = require('./routes/index');
            var users = require('./routes/users');

            var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
            var app = express();

            //View Engine
            app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
            app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
            app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

            // Set Static Folder
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

            // Body Parser MW
            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

            var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
            if(env == 'development'){
                app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));  
            }else{
                app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
            }

            app.use('/', index);
            app.use('/users', users);

            app.listen(port, function(){
                console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
            });
```

package.json

```
{
      "name": "attend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Attendance System",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
        "ejs": "^2.5.5",
        "express": "^4.14.1",
        "mysql": "^2.13.0"
      }
    }
```

index.js

```
    var express = require('express');

        var router = express.Router();

        router.get('/', function(req, res){
           res.render('index.html');    
        });

        module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Got solution. There was an error of port. A2Hosting requires server to listen either of two specific port 65535 or 49152